# How to get the sequence of messages in reverse order

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tqtz.png)I am trying to make a chat app and as per video lecture I have added reversed to the list where i am getting the snapshot but it is not reflecting there in app. I am attaching the code. Kindly help and I would be more than happy to provide any clarifications if required.

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: _firestore.collection('messages').snapshots(),
      builder: (context,snapshot){
        if(snapshot.hasData) {
          final messages = snapshot.data.docs.reversed;
          List<MessageBubble> messageBubbles=[];
          for(var message in messages)
          {
            final messageText=message.get('text');
            final messageSender=message.get('sender');
            final currentUser= loggedInUser.email;
            final messageBubble=
            MessageBubble(sender:messageSender,
                text:messageText,
                 isMe:currentUser==messageSender);
            messageBubbles.add(messageBubble);
     
          }
          return Expanded(
            flex:8,
            child: ListView(
              reverse:true,
                padding:EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal:10,vertical:20),
                children: messageBubbles
            ),
          );
        }
        else {
          return Column(
              children: []
          );
        }
      },
    );
```

this picture shows that the last message i sent was, "hello i am texting for the first time" it is neither at the top of previous messages nor at the bottom but anywhere in between randomly. I want it to be at the bottom always and also want the screen to always remain at the bottom by default until user scrolls it up.

Picture where collection is there a snapsho[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Gst8.jpg)t.

Answer (score 0):

You are reversing the list in two places:

- Directly on the list.

  ```dart
  final messages = snapshot.data.docs.reversed;
  ```
- In the `ListView`.

  ```dart
  ListView(
    reverse:true,
    padding:EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal:10,vertical:20),
    children: messageBubbles
  ),
  ```

You can get rid of the one in the `ListView` and just reverse the list itself.

Comment: In list view I used reverse to stay at the bottom of the screen always and directly on list so that my list gets reversed as it was explained in a video.

Comment: Further the items are being added in random order I want something like any normal messaging app

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "random order" and "like any normal messaging app"? Do you want it to be sorted alphabetically or by timestamp?

Comment: Also, it would help to post the structure of the messages collection.

Comment: By random order means that when i am texting a message then it is going anywhere in the list of messages that is neither at topmost nor at bottom but anywhere in between. By " like normal messaging app " i mean messages should be ordered as per time stamp.

Comment: I am not getting an option to paste the picture so i am attaching it in my question itself. Kindly check it out. Really grateful for your time and help.

Comment: What field are in each document in the messages collection?

Comment: Do you have a timestamp field?

Comment: it has only text and sender

Comment: I was just following what was in the video because i am new to it. In video it was working fine but when i tried that's not working. I hope you got my point what i want. To create a normal messaging app. But in my case even on using revered the messages are unsorted. Further I always want when i signin it must be at the bottom i.e. where last message was

Comment: Do you have a link to the video?

Comment: Or if you are clear with what I am trying to implement i would be really grateful if you could give your way out. I don't want to stick to this method if that's wrong

Comment: Okay. Can you post where you're setting the data to the messages collection?

Comment: Yes  i am attaching image in question itself here there is no option to attach

Comment: I meant the part of the code where you call `FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('messages').doc().set()`

Comment: It is the first line present in the code above. _firestore is the instance of FirebaseFirestore

Comment: Check the code again. The one up there is for *reading* the data from Firestore and not for *writing* to Firestore.